# Fetch backup details of Azure VM from python sdk

Tags: python, azure, sdk, backup

Which Properties I need to query for getting azure VM's backup policy enabled or not using Python Azure SDk. Any references and examples are appreciated

I referred to below snipped from azure docs, but i dont find backup section here..

```
def get_vm(compute_client):
    vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, expand='instanceView')
    print("hardwareProfile")
    print("   vmSize: ", vm.hardware_profile.vm_size)
    print("\nstorageProfile")
    print("  imageReference")
    print("    publisher: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.publisher)
    print("    offer: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.offer)
    print("    sku: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.sku)
    print("    version: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.version)
    print("  osDisk")
    print("    osType: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.os_type.value)
    print("    name: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.name)
    print("    createOption: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.create_option.value)
    print("    caching: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.caching.value)
    print("\nosProfile")
    print("  computerName: ", vm.os_profile.computer_name)
    print("  adminUsername: ", vm.os_profile.admin_username)
    print("  provisionVMAgent: {0}".format(vm.os_profile.windows_configuration.provision_vm_agent))
    print("  enableAutomaticUpdates: {0}".format(vm.os_profile.windows_configuration.enable_automatic_updates))
    print("\nnetworkProfile")
    for nic in vm.network_profile.network_interfaces:
        print("  networkInterface id: ", nic.id)
    print("\nvmAgent")
    print("  vmAgentVersion", vm.instance_view.vm_agent.vm_agent_version)
    print("    statuses")
    for stat in vm_result.instance_view.vm_agent.statuses:
        print("    code: ", stat.code)
        print("    displayStatus: ", stat.display_status)
        print("    message: ", stat.message)
        print("    time: ", stat.time)
    print("\ndisks");
    for disk in vm.instance_view.disks:
        print("  name: ", disk.name)
        print("  statuses")
        for stat in disk.statuses:
            print("    code: ", stat.code)
            print("    displayStatus: ", stat.display_status)
            print("    time: ", stat.time)
    print("\nVM general status")
    print("  provisioningStatus: ", vm.provisioning_state)
    print("  id: ", vm.id)
    print("  name: ", vm.name)
    print("  type: ", vm.type)
    print("  location: ", vm.location)
    print("\nVM instance status")
    for stat in vm.instance_view.statuses:
        print("  code: ", stat.code)
        print("  displayStatus: ", stat.display_status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the [Backup Protected Items - List api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/backupprotecteditems/list) to do it.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
import requests

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxx'
VM_NAME = 'xxx'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='xxx',
    secret='xxx',
    tenant='xxx'
)

BASE_URL = "https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/your_vault_name/backupProtectedItems?api-version=2019-05-13&"

myfilter="$filter=backupManagementType eq 'AzureIaasVM' and itemType eq 'VM' and policyName eq 'DailyPolicy'"

BASE_URL = BASE_URL + myfilter

headers = {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer '+ credentials.token["access_token"]
}

response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)

print(response.content)
```

Note that you should take care of `response.content`, write code to convert it to real json format. Then fetch the related values from the json.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The Backup is a different service in Azure. It's not a setting in Azure VM.
You can follow the Quickstart *[Back up a virtual machine in Azure with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-cli)*.
It will show you how to backup a VM via CLI or Protal :)